# Spring boot doesn't read DB configuration from yml file

Tags: java, database, spring-boot

I have this config file:

```
liquibase:
  enabled: true
  change-log: classpath:/db/changelog/db.changelog-master.yml
management:
  security:
      enabled: false
server:
  port: 8080
spring:
  datasource:
    driverClassName: org.h2.Driver
    url: jdbc:h2:file:./target/h2db/db/develop;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1
    username: sa
    password:
  h2:
    console:
        enabled: true
```

When I try to check datasorce it connects to "jdbc:h2:mem:testdb" anyway:

```
@Component
public class AfterInit implements CommandLineRunner {

    @Autowired
    DataSource dataSource;

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        out.println(dataSource);
    }
}
```

Why spring boot can't find proper database config?

Answer (score 0):

When I changed dependency from `runtime("com.h2database:h2")` to `compile("com.h2database:h2")` Datasource became work. 
Can anybody explain me what's happend?